# msiOpenDataBaseModes != 0 causes exception

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I don't understand this at all.

When I try to open an MSI file in anything else than read only mode, I get an exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
>   HelpLink=Msi.chm#9006 HResult=-2147467259
>   Message=OpenDatabase,DatabasePath,OpenMode Source=Msi API Error
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259 StackTrace:    at
>   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData)    at WindowsInstaller.Installer.OpenDatabase(String
>   DatabasePath, Object OpenMode)    at web based release
>   manager.AjaxFileHandler.updateMSIProperty(String msiFile, String
>   msiProperty, String value) in C:\Users\obfuscated\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\Projects\web based release
>   manager\AjaxFileHandler.ashx.cs:line 28    at web based release
>   manager.AjaxFileHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   C:\Users\obfuscated\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\web based
>   release manager\AjaxFileHandler.ashx.cs:line 143    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I **can** read a property from the msi with the working code below, so I know the filepath is correct:

```
public static string GetMSIProperty(string msiFile, string msiProperty)
{
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        Type classType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
        Object installerObj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
        WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = installerObj as WindowsInstaller.Installer;
        Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(msiFile, 0);

        string sql = String.Format("SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='{0}'", msiProperty);

        View view = database.OpenView(sql);
        WindowsInstaller.Record record = null;
        view.Execute(record);
        record = view.Fetch();

        if (record != null)
        {
            retVal = record.get_StringData(1).ToString();
        }
        else
            retVal = "Property Not Found";
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(installer);
        return retVal;
}
```

The code that causes the problems:

```
public void updateMSIProperty(string msiFile, string msiProperty, string value)
{
    Type classType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
    Object installerObj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
    WindowsInstaller.Installer installer = installerObj as WindowsInstaller.Installer;

    var mode = MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeDirect;
    Database database = installer.OpenDatabase(msiFile, mode);  //throws the exception!

    string sql = String.Format("UPDATE `Property` SET `Value`='{0}' WHERE `Property`='{1}'", value, msiProperty);

    View view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();

    return;
}
```

And the two functions are run from the same piece of code as:

```
if(GetMSIProperty(path, "UpgradeCode") != theProductsUpgradeCode)
    updateMSIProperty(path, "UpgradeCode",theProductsUpgradeCode);
```

The company I work for is migrating towards releasing software as msi's.
No problem, except, the company consists of alot of engineers that are good at what they do, part of this is programming tools used for calculations.
They are not computer scientists, and most of them wouldn't know the difference between OS2 and Office 365...

Up to this point most of the departments have created some release system, that can create an msi, and install the product, however they have not really grasped what all those product/package attributes do.

I thought I would help them, and at our webfrontend where they publish the msi's correct this, by replacing the UpgradeCodes (guid), and insert some of the other data they usually forget, such as manufacturer.. certificates  etc..

But I can't get my code to update the MSIs.

**Update:**

- Obfuscated product name a bit more, to protect job.
- Have tried adding `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(installer)` with no success

Comment: [`OpenDatabase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369434(v=vs.85).aspx): "If the method fails, you can obtain extended error information by using the [LastErrorRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369430(v=vs.85).aspx) method."

Comment: Well I have tried that, but gets...

Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

also before anyone wonders.. yes I have permissions to write to the file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as Chris's advice, I'd stay away from the entire COM-type activation because it's completely unnecessary. There is a perfectly good Win32 API that can be used via p/invoke. Here's a minimal example I used once:

```
  public class MsiInvoke
{

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiOpenDatabase(string filename, int persist, out IntPtr dbhandle);
    public const int MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT = 2;

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiCloseDatabase(string filename, int persist, out IntPtr dbhandle);

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiDatabaseCommit(IntPtr hDb);

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiViewClose(IntPtr hView);

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiDatabaseOpenView(IntPtr hDb, string query, out IntPtr hView);

    [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MsiViewExecute (IntPtr hView, IntPtr hRec); 
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr hDb = IntPtr.Zero;
        int res = MsiInvoke.MsiOpenDatabase("setup.msi",MsiInvoke.MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT, out hDb);
        string qinsert = "UPDATE `Control` set `Control`.`Text`= 'Something' WHERE `Dialog_`='License_Dialog' AND `Control`='License'";
        IntPtr hView=IntPtr.Zero;
        res = MsiInvoke.MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDb, qinsert, out hView);
        res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewExecute(hView, IntPtr.Zero);
        res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewClose(hView);
        res = MsiInvoke.MsiDatabaseCommit(hDb);
    }
}
```

Note that this lazy program should include a call to MsiCloseHandle() on each handle, but doesn't because that happens when it finishes anyway.

Comment: FWIW, WiX DTF interop library is just a bunch of (well designed and tested) classes that abstract all of this.  Under the hood it's using P/Invoke.  I used to do it the way you suggest (typically using Rich's MSIInterop.cs)  but the DTF way is far superior IMO.

Comment: Just for anyone stumbling on this later on:

In case you wan't to reopen the database within the same application instance you need to close the handle for this you either need to use the MSIHANDLE instead of IntPtr, or:

--------------
[DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int MsiCloseAllHandles();
--------------
MsiInvoke.MsiCloseAllHandles()

Comment: Don't forget to call MsiCommitDatabase also otherwise you risk database corruption. See the remarks section at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I added a note that this doesn't close handles as it should, but there is already a database commit call there.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer XML (WiX) has a feature called Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) that has a very nice interop assembly for MSI called Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll.  This assembly has a class called Database that has a constructor like:

```
public Database(
    string filePath,
    DatabaseOpenMode mode
)
```

A simple example is:

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;    
using(Database database = new Database(@"C:\test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
{
  ...
}
```

There is also a QDatabase class that implements a LINQ to MSI pattern to make it easy to treat the Properties table as an entity and query / update accordingly.

```
using(var database = new QDatabase(@"C:\test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
// or in custom action
using(var qdatabase = session.Database.AsQueryable() )
```

I highly advise this so you can focus on the code you are trying to write and not how to interop with MSI.

Comment: I like this answer, it is clean and neat, however I gave the "accept" to PhilDW, as the code was ready to use, and it was the only thing I was missing before the test case was a success. - I don't really have time to redo this project, but next time I need to handle MSI's, I should use DTF!

Comment: The important part is that you avoid COM (both solutions do) and you remember to always close your handles (DTF excels here because all of the classes implement IDisposable).   The interop.cs approach I fine when you only need to call a couple functions and don't want to have another.DLL in your solution.  But for anything beyond that DTF is vastly superior.

Comment: Yes, the handle closing did cause a surprise, even though it was easily fixed (notice the comment for that solution ;) ),

I must admit that I had totally forgotten about it in the COM based solutions, but now it is in place in the server side, and the get function is updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: At the very least, look through the DTF (open) source code.  It was written by a MSFT developer named Jason who really, really knows his MSI stuff.  He knows all these pitfalls and already addressed them for us. :)